# keycloak client protocol mapper (script mapper) to add request header into token

Tags: keycloak, mapper

When I'm requesting a token from keycloak I want a specific header value (or extra form data) that was supplied in the request to be put in the JWT payload of the generated token. I've tried using a Script Mapper to get access to header values but I can't see how to get access to header values or data in the form data sent in any of the available script variables: `user`, `realm`, `userSession`, `keyclockSession`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get access to request headers using keycloakSession object, something like

```
keycloakSession.getContext().getRequestHeaders().getRequestHeader("User-Agent")
```

If you check the code for DefaultEvaluationContext class, that is how they add the User-Agent header.

Comment: For mobile app can we use this to retreive device_id , device_model , etc to insert as claim?

Comment: This is working for Basic Auth, for Oauth2 when I set clientId secret I am getting empty array for getRequestHeader. Not sure if there is any other way to get request headers.

Comment: It worked perfectly for me, using OIDC Confidential with client_id and secret and a custom http header. Thank you!

Comment: so it seems that a custom mapper needs to be written in order to implement this functionality, right?